# Does carrierwave_direct expose your s3 credentials?

Tags: security, amazon-s3, carrierwave

We are considering using carrierwave_direct for uploading files directly to s3 from the user's browser. The form generated by carrierwave_direct includes our aws_access_key, and a "signature", which is generated by the following code:

```
def signature
  Base64.encode64(
    OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(
      OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1'),
      aws_secret_access_key, policy
    )
  ).gsub("\n","")
end
```

The `policy` argument is a method, and is generated using Time.now, so presumably that makes it very hard for an attacker to figure out our `aws_secret_access_key`. However, if just the aws_access_key and this signature are enough to authenticate as this s3 user (even if it's time-limited), why would an attacker need our `aws_secret_access_key`? Can't they just reload the page to get a signature that will work for a period of time?  What am I missing here?

The reason I'm concerned is because we're using the same credentials in other parts of our app to do things that we definitely don't want arbitrary users to be able to do, and fog/carrierwave don't seem to provide a way to use one set of credentials for one operation, and another elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature only authenticates the user with permission to perform the action allowed by the policy document that the signature was generating by signing.  Change a single byte in the policy, and the signature is invalid.  (You can prove this to yourself by tweaking it manually).

The AWS access key is intended to be safe to expose.  The AWS secret is what you should never expose, and the signature does not contain enough information to reverse-engineer your secret from it in any practical way other than brute force... the keyspace is considered too large for this to be practical.

Still, it would be best (as always, not specifically here) to use a different key/secret pair that only has the minimum permissions required to accomplish the purpose, and to periodically rotate them.

Comment: Thanks! I did more investigating as well, and one of the critical things that I missed initially is that the signature encrypts the policy, and the policy is very limited such that it only allows uploading to a specific key-prefix.